# C++ error: error: expected primary-expression before '||' token

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and decided to make something with the knowledge I have of other programming languages.  I decided to make a simple calculator to make quick calculations but something is off.  I tried to only allow certain symbols for operations but it keeps coming up with these errors:

```
12:19: error: expected primary-expression before '||' token
12:22: error: expected primary-expression before '/' token
12:24: error: expected primary-expression before '||' token
12:29: error: expected primary-expression before '||' token
12:33: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
```

Here's my code:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
char symbol;
int number1;
int number2;
  std::cout << "Enter an operator ";
  std::cin >> symbol;
  if (symbol != + || / || * || -){
  std::cout << "That isn't an operator, please fix it.";
  std::cin >> symbol;
  }
  std::cout << "Choose a number ";
  std::cin >> number1;
  std::cout << "Choose a second number ";
  std::cin >> number2;
  if (symbol == '+'){
  std::cout << number1 + number2;
}
if (symbol == '*'){
    std::cout << number1 * number2;

    }
    if (symbol == '-'){
        std::cout << number1 - number2;
        }
        if(symbol == '/' ){
            std::cout << number1 / number2;
            }
}
```

Comment: `if (symbol != + || / || * || -)` - what is that supposed to mean?

Comment: I think you need this, if
(
symbol != '+' ||
symbol != '/' ||
symbol != '*' ||
symbol != '-' 
)

Comment: How is it you know that `symbol == '+'` in some places, but you can't figure out why `symbol == +` is wrong in another? And that's not how the OR operator works. You should find a tutorial online rather than just pounding on keys and hoping things work.

Answer (score 1):

First, the correct syntax is

```
if (symbol != '+' || symbol != '/'  || symbol != '*' || symbol != '-')
```

But then, this `if` is useless because your `symbol` cannot be equal to all these at the same time. So it is equivalent to `if (true)`.

You wanted `&&` (and) instead of `||` (or) and loop until user types an operator; something like:

```
std::cin >> symbol;
while (symbol != '+' && symbol != '/'  && symbol != '*' && symbol != '-') {
    std::cout << "That isn't an operator, please fix it.";
    std::cin >> symbol;
}
```